# How to define synonym or opposite keys with l3keys2e?

Tags: expl3, package-writing, l3keys

In my package, there are several bool-valued options that are interrelated. How should I reflect the relations in `\keys_define`?

Take a concrete example, with the following code, does it define the key `option-one-alt` to be synonym of `option-one`, and `option-one-oppo` to be their opposite? If not, what should a correct definition look like?

```
\keys_define:nn { my-keys }
  {
    , option-one       .bool_set:N   = \l__crthm_option_one_bool
    , option-one       .initial:n    = { true }
    , option-one-alt   .bool_set:N   = \l__crthm_option_one_bool
    , option-one-alt   .initial:n    = { true }
    , option-one-oppo  .bool_set:N   = \l__crthm_option_one_bool
    , option-one-oppo  .initial:n    = { false }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your code doesn't do that, instead the `option-one-oppo` will behave the same as `option-one` and `option-one-alt`, and the start value (`.initial:n`) of `\l__crthm_option_one_bool` will be false.

Instead you can use `.bool_set_inverse:N` for `option-one-oppo`, and could define `option-one-alt` in terms of `option-one` if you'd like (but that's not really necessary, the current definition will be faster at use time).

```
\keys_define:nn { my-keys }
  {
    , option-one       .bool_set:N   = \l__crthm_option_one_bool
    , option-one       .initial:n    = { true }
    , option-one-alt   .bool_set:N   = \l__crthm_option_one_bool
    , option-one-oppo  .bool_set_inverse:N = \l__crthm_option_one_bool
  }
```

The other suggestion (defining in terms of another key) would use the `.meta:n` type:

```
\keys_define:nn { my-keys } { option-one-alt .meta:n = { option-one = {#1} } }
```

Also your example looks like you're having a misconception of what `.initial:n` does, this only sets a value once, so `.initial:n` will behave the same as if you use `\keys_set:nn {<set>} { <key> = <value> }` at that place. So setting your `.initial:n` once is fine.

If you intended to define the behaviour if the key is used without a value that would be `option-one .default:n = true` not `.initial:n`.

Comment: Thank you for this! Indeed, I didn't know about `.default:n` and have been misusing `.initial:n` for many options.